# Form to update multiple items of a database at the same time

Tags: php, html, database, forms

I am trying to create a page that will show the items in a table and all fields for each of the items. The purpose is to give the user the possibility to update the item's details online.

I have around 14 fields in my table and was planning on doing it like the below. Would it make sense? Or would there be a more efficient way to do this?

```
<form>
(query all items in table)
while (...) {
    <span class="details">NAME: </span>
    <input name="name" value="<?php echo $info['name']; ?>">
    <span class="details">CATEGORY: </span>
    <input name="category" value="<?php echo $info['category']; ?>"
...
... and so on 12 more times
}
<button to submit the form>
</form>
```

And then, I would like to update in the database ONLY those fields that have been updated by the user. Should I check one by one each field? Or is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently using this code for disabling all fields that not changed:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.input').change(function() {
        $(this).addClass('changed');
    });
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
     $('form').find('.input:not(.changed)').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
});
</script>
```

I added 'input' class to all form element (select, textarea, input, etc), then, the script watching them if they changed then it adds another class named 'changed', and later, when the submit button clicked, the script disables all element that not changed.

Comment: This is a great idea! Thanks! Just one question, how would I get the submitted values with PHP? Do I have to POST all the input sent and see if they are empty?

Answer (score 0):

Akam's answer is brilliant - applying disabled="disabled" to unchanged input elements will in fact prevent them to be submitted, and only the changed variables will be then sent to the server.

What I have to add here is ... `.changed` here already checks if the submitted/entered value differs from the original one. But you can also easily do a comparison of values with original values at submit (with `===` for example, or if you already want to do some sanitation/validation you can use regular expressions or such)

This are all elegant javascript (or jQuery) solutions, but I have seen (silly ;-) people also doing comparisons like that at the server side (e.g. with php). However, then you are either bouncing the original values back and forth - which is not so bad (meaning: you have to pass the new and the old values back to the server  -  but do not read them again from the database - then you loose more than if you would just update all form values in the database).